# How to resolve api url issue in angular 6

Tags: angular6, angular5, angular7

I am trying to run this application in my local but not working.Many times i tried but i could not find the issue.I think api url issue.If i run this application i am getting below the error.How to resolve this issue? How can i run this application without error?

```
zone.js:2935 GET http://salembrothers.ca/app/api/getSettings/social 404 (Not Found)  
products:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://salembrothers.ca/app/api/getSettings/social' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

For full code :  https://github.com/MarouaneSH/Angular-6-Shopping-cart-with-Laravel

api.service.ts:

```
import { HttpClient , HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators/catchError';
import { ErrorObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx'


const apiUrl =  "http://salembrothers.ca/app/api";

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {


  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  get(path,params:HttpParams = new HttpParams()){
      return this.http.get(`${apiUrl}/${path}`, {params})
             .pipe(
               catchError(this.handleError)
            );
  }


 post(path,params){
      return this.http.post(`${apiUrl}/${path}`, params)
                .pipe(
                  catchError(this.handleError)
                );
 }

  handleError(err:any){
    return Observable.throw(err);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says 'has been blocked by CORS policy', you need to enable CORS in your API server, your API server/framework may also require to whitelist your 'http://localhost:4200' where you are running Angular.

Comment: I am also facing same issue.. I am running from my xampp local host server

Comment: How to enable api server?